# Adding new field in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, field-calculator

I am trying to add new field to my table based on two other existing fields.
In the field Calculator it's quite simple:

[image: My Goal]

When I am trying to run as a Python code I got into trouble, Here's my code:

```
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()    
vLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('1m_Cases', QVariant.Int)])
vLayer.updateFields()
for f in vLayer.getFeatures(): 
        f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex('1m_Cases'), f(['J_TotalCases'] *1000000)/ f['Pop'])
vLayer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change the code like below, which should work:

```
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
vLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('1m_Cases', QVariant.Int)])
vLayer.updateFields()
vLayer.startEditing()
for f in vLayer.getFeatures():
    f['1m_Cases'] = f['J_TotalCases'] *1000000/ f['Pop']
    vLayer.updateFeature(f)
vLayer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Can you not mix the use of dataprovider and editing session? Either use only the dataprovider or the editing buffer. Thanks

Comment: I tried to run the code but I got the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'QVariant' and 'int'??

Comment: I've tried the code, but there was no error. The error indicates, that in the line with f['J_TotalCases'] *1000000/ f['Pop'] something goes wrong. May be you'll try: from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

Comment: Thanks it was a mistype on my end. It's working now

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @eurojam but using only the editing buffer, like in QGIS GUI.

```
from qgis.core import edit

vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(vLayer)
    vLayer.addAttribute(QgsField('1m_Cases', QVariant.Int))
    for f in vLayer.getFeatures():
        f['1m_Cases'] = f['J_TotalCases'] *1000000/ f['Pop']
        vLayer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, will try it now...